# BroadcastReceiver for monitoring phone call state does not work properly for Android O API 27

Tags: java, android, kotlin, telephonymanager, android-8.1-oreo

I have a broadcast receiver class which identifies phone call states, (outgoing, incoming, `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`, `CALL_STATE_IDLE` ) it works fine for android N and for lower versions, but for Android O, receiver can't identify if call has been end, there is no `CALL_STATE_IDLE` state, but identifies outgoing, incoming and `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` states correctly

```
private fun startListening(context: Context) {
    val telManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as? TelephonyManager
    telManager?.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
}


    private val phoneListener = object : PhoneStateListener() {
    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, incomingNumber: String) {
        Log.e("CALL_STATE", "calling number $incomingNumber")
        try {
            when (state) {
                TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
                    Log.e("CALL_STATE", "CALL_STATE_RINGING")
                }
                TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                    Log.e("CALL_STATE", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK")
                }

                TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                    Log.e("CALL_STATE", "CALL_STATE_IDLE")
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.e("CALL_STATE", "CALL_STATE_IDLE")
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyPhoneCallStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="989999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also what I have found is that, if call is incoming, it correctly identifies when `CALL_STATE_IDLE`  state fires

What I'm missing?